# What happens if a user deletes his/her Google account?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am exploring using Firebase authentication for my React app. I am including google as one of the sign-in providers. When a user signs in using his/her google account for the first time, I will insert a new `user` document into my `users` collection (using mongo DB), setting its `id` to the `uid` from the firebase user object.

Whenever that user signs in, I retrieve the corresponding `user` document from my own db using the `uid` field.

Am I right to say that the user would never be able to retrieve his account information on my app again if he deletes his google account? Seems a little risky. If google (or any other third party provider) somehow has a policy that permanently erases user accounts upon deletion, those users will also never be able to retrieve their information stored on my app again. How can I prevent such a situation from happening?

Comment: Well, *you* still have access to any data you've saved about the user.  Which could include any information they share with you.  If they delete their Google account then I would certainly expect them to no longer be able to authenticate via Google.  But if they need access to information in your system then they could contact you to help retrieve that information.

Comment: OAuth should be used to reduce friction at signup/login: not as a replacement for first-party credential data

Comment: @David That's true but even when they contact me, there is no way I can authenticate them already. Assuming I do not ask for and store other first-party credential data.

Comment: @jalen_blue: Which is a good reason for the user to not delete their accounts if they still want access to those accounts.  This seems like a pretty extreme edge case.  But if it is a concern then you could always have users provide you with an alternate email address for identification purposes in case they lose access to their account.  Any time a user requests help accessing their data you can send an email to that alternate address to validate their authorization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, Firebase Authentication supports multiple authentication providers.  If you only support one of them, you certainly run the risk of the user losing access to their data in your project if they end up deleting or getting locked out of their provider's account.  There is no easy way of recovering from this situation, requiring some sort of manual intervention on your end.

If you want to defend against someone losing access to their data in your project, you should allow them to use more than one auth providers with the same account.  This involves [linking the provider to the existing Firebase account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/account-linking).  From the documentation:

> You can allow users to sign in to your app using multiple authentication providers by linking auth provider credentials to an existing user account. Users are identifiable by the same Firebase user ID regardless of the authentication provider they used to sign in. For example, a user who signed in with a password can link a Google account and sign in with either method in the future. Or, an anonymous user can link a Facebook account and then, later, sign in with Facebook to continue using your app.

If the user has multiple linked providers, then they can use any one of them to sign in to your app and access their data under the same Firebase user ID.  You can enable the user to link any number of supported providers using application code you write according to the documentation.